# How to create DataFrame with scraped data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a web scraper that pulls data and categorizes it in pandas data frame.

All of my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class CaseCrawler:
    def __init__(self, starting_url, depth):
        self.starting_url = starting_url
        self.depth = depth
        self.cases = []

    def crawl(self):
        self.get_case_info(self.starting_url)
        return 

    def get_case_info(self, link):
        # opening up connection
        uClient = uReq(link)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()

        # html parsing
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

        case = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"bbWrapper"})


        for point in case:
            name = point.b.text
            body = point.text
            tag_block = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"blockStatus-message"})

            for tagger in tag_block:
                 tag_title = tagger.findAll("dl", {"class":"pairs pairs--columns pairs--spaced pairs--fixedSmall"})


        #pandas dataframe
        ##tag_df = pd.DataFrame(tag_title, index=tag_title.dt)
        print(tag_title[0])



        tag_df.to_csv("temp.csv")

crawler = CaseCrawler('https://www.yargikararlari.net/konu/iikya-gore-ortakligin-giderilmesi-davasi-acilabilmesi-icin-usulune-gore-borclu-ortagin-alacaklisi-iik-m-121.350/', 0)
crawler.crawl()
```

In the end of the code I want to scrape a block of info in a data frame with pandas

Here is the my problematic part of this website:
[2rows 2columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryYWm.png)

When I run the code it creates indented and unnecessary spaced csv file: [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqiYD.png)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the output csv? "Indented and unnecessarily spaced" doesn't tell us enough. Also, could you try 'lxml' as the passer and let us know if that produces different results.

Comment: I added the csv file. I do not know much about lxml. But I will try it

Comment: I now know what the problem is but it is going to take me a little time to re-write your code to sort it out, please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the construction of the dataframe. `tag_title`is a resultset and has no attribute `dt`. Also the code in the page you are trying to scrape has a lot of extraneous white space. As I suggested above use 'lxml' as your passer and change the line:

```
tag_df = pd.DataFrame(tag_title, index=tag_title.dt)
```

to

```
    idx=[]
    dta=[]
    for title in tag_title:
        idx.append(title.find("dt").text)
        dta.append(title.find("dd").text.strip())
    tag_df = pd.DataFrame(dta, index=idx)
```

and I think you'll be closer to what you want.

Comment: It works great now, thanks. But I need to ask you: Is this the best way to scrape those data from there? And you didn't use lxml for it, did you?

Comment: 1. I did use lxml. I, and this is personal preference, never use html.parser. 2. I tend to take a practical attitude to web scraping if it works don't mess with it!